# Not understanding higher order functions (problem example using javascript)

Tags: javascript, callback, higher-order-functions

I'm studying Javascript basics, particularly higher order functions, at the moment. I have read many articles and watched as many videos where people explain the basic definition and demonstrate the most basic construction of a higher order function. However, when I encounter an actual problem, I am lost. Here is an example (this is just for my personal study, not for a grade or for work):

> Write a maybe function that, given a predicate (a function that returns a boolean value) and any other function, only calls the latter if the former returns true: maybe(x => x > 100, myFn). If the predicate returns true, the value of x should be passed to myFn. If the predicate returns false, x should be returned unchanged.

I don't understand how to pass the value of x from one function to another...

I solved this by adding a number argument to maybe, in addition to the predicate function and callback function. However, only two parameters are specified in the prompt, so I guess I'm not doing it correctly. Here is what I did:

```
//predicate (evaluates to a boolean)
const notZero = function(x) {
    //console.log('predicate runs!');
    return x !== 0;
}

//callback (does something within the main function)
const plusOne = function(x) {
    //console.log('callback runs!');
    return x + 1;
}

//checking if my predicate works
//test(notZero(1), true); // => test passed!

//another callback
const myFn = function(x) {
    return x - 100;
}

//main function
function maybe(number, predicate, callback) {
    if (predicate(number) === true) {
        //console.log('predicate === true');
        //console.log(callback(number));
        return callback(number);
    } else {
        return number;
    }
}



test(maybe(1, notZero, plusOne), 2);
test(maybe(0, notZero, plusOne), 0);

test(maybe(101, x => x > 100, myFn), 1);
test(maybe(99, x => x > 100, myFn), 99);
```

**EDIT:** As shared below, `maybe` can now take only 2 parameters (the predicate and the callback) because  it now returns a function whose parameter is `number`. That's the idea I was looking for.

```
function maybe(predicate, callback) {

    return function (number) {
        if (predicate(number) === true) {
            return callback(number);
        } else {
            return number;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Your code looks fine. Where is the problem?

Comment: Maaz, the prompt only specifies 2 parameters (the predicate and the callback). Yes, my tests pass, but I am concerned that it is possible to solve this without adding a number parameter...I don't know how to solve it in that case.

Comment: How do you plan to pass the number to the predicate in the first place?

Comment: Thank you, I realized that I need to immediately return a function which takes number as a parameter, instead of including number in maybe's parameter list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's technically impossible. `x` is locked out of the world in `predicate`'s scope. There's no way you may extract it out of this function.

Apart from that, as you correctly assume in your code, we logically need to communicate `x` to both `predicate` & `callback`. Otherwise, what's the point of `maybe` at all?

Since then, your solution is one of very few possible ones.

You may "decorate" it nicer with currying. The idea is precisely identical as in your code but if you'll do so, you will be able to call the final function exactly with 2 arguments.

```
const setMaybeBase => x => (predicate, callback) => predicate(x) ? callback(x) : x;

// use it later this way
const maybe42 = setMaybeBase(42);
maybe42(yourFn, yourFnTwo);
```

This is a *huge* overkill unless the argument you pass to `setMaybeBase` is for example a complex object you are going to work with.

---

Alternatively, you might go wild & use a function to *get* the `x` as well.

Nevertheless, always remember that the easiest solution is the best one.

Here is a real-world example of maybe function taken straight from [node.js repo](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/921493e2287aa895679620155b5288b2e1587bfd/lib/fs.js#L131):

```
function maybeCallback(cb) {

  if (typeof cb === 'function')

    return cb;



  throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK(cb);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I realized that I needed to immediately return a function which takes number as a parameter, instead of including number in maybe's parameter list. Before, I didn't realize that the way to pass a value from one function to another, is by returning a new function to which the passing occurs (from the top-level function's parameters to the inner function's parameters). Much clearer now.